# mutate rows in column if specific condition is met

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

How can I subtract the value 4 from the mass column of all humans in the column species?

I've unsuccesfully tried this

```
starwars <- starwars%>%
mutate_if(species=="human", mass = mass - 4)
```

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mutate along with ifelse.  The first argument of ifelse is a condition, the second is what it returns if the condition is TRUE, and the third is what it returns if the condition is FALSE.

```
starwars <- starwars %>%
  mutate(mass = ifelse(species == "human", mass - 4, mass)
```